# Find the position of slash 1

Tags: java, string

```
String uRL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a URL ");  int colon = uRL.indexOf(":");                                                                          

System.out.println("The position of colon is "+  colon);

String protocol = uRL.substring(0,colon);
System.out.println("the protocol is "+ protocol);

// Declare Statements, extract and print the second part
String restOFURL = uRL.substring(colon+7);
System.out.println("The rest of Url is "+restOFURL);

int positionOfSlash1 = restOFURL.indexOf("/");
System.out.println(positionOfSlash1);
```

Ok so the input will be a URL, let just say for example the URL is http://www.pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html

URL will always have let say the HTTP FTTP: // www. and etc

The project that Im doing is to break down URL into different parts and I'm stuck on one of the question

The question ask me to find the position Of Slash 1, as you see in the code rest of URL is
pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html the position is  15 for the first /

while http://www.pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html is 26, this is what I want.

There was a suggestion that said to first find how many characters there is from start of the string to period "www." and add the value to positionOfSlash1

Comment: I did     System.out.println(positionOfSlash1+uRL.indexOf(".")+1); I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it

Comment: Why don't you just add the removed part length? int positionOfSlash1 = restOFURL.indexOf("/") +protocol.length + 7

Comment: After testing this, it didnt fully work for all different kind of URL

Answer (score 0):

the `indexOf()` method also take a second parameter (`fromIndex`) which is used to specify to say indexOf from where you try to lookup for the parameter:

```
int positionOfSlash1 = restOFURL.indexOf("/", colon + 3);
positionOfSlash1 = uRL.indexOf("/", colon + 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I would do it using [Java Regex API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html"));
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("http://www.pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html"));
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("Hello WOrld"));
    }

    static int indexOfDomainNameSeparator(String url) {
        String regex = "(?<![:/])/";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(url);

        // If found, return the index; otherwise, return -1
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
15
26
-1
```

The regex, `(?<![:/])/` means `/` not preceded by a `:` or `/`. In regex terminology, **'not preceded by'** is known as the **[negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**. The thing inside `[ ]` is known as [character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

**Alternatively**, using [`String#indexOf(int,%20int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) and [`String.html#indexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html"));
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("http://www.pcwebopedia.com/files/index.html"));
        System.out.println(indexOfDomainNameSeparator("Hello WOrld"));
    }

    static int indexOfDomainNameSeparator(String url) {
        int indexOfColon = url.indexOf(':');
        if (indexOfColon != -1) {
            return url.indexOf('/', indexOfColon + 3);// Starting from indexOfColon + 3
        } else {
            return url.indexOf('/');
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
15
26
-1
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, now I understand how to do this thanks!